# filling in gaps in concrete patio

Tags: concrete

I have several 2" wide by 6' long spaces between the original patio slab and the newer slab that was poured after original construction of the house. The porch is covered so no moisture is getting  inbut I need to fill/patch these gaps. I need some help.

Comment: Was this where the original forms were located? Typically those would have been left-in-place to fill in the gap.

Comment: There's two ways you can go with this - 1) as durable as possible, but a pain to remove and replace when it finally fails, or 2) not as durable, but easy to spruce up annually.  For option 2, you might want to consider just dumping in some polymeric sand.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a gap filler like Sikaflex self leveling sealant.